# My (not ISP-owned) internet router-modem combo reset to defaults

Tags: wireless-networking, router, factory-defaults

After several years of working 100% reliably, my third-party internet router-modem combo suddenly "forgot" the WiFi names and passwords I had created and reverted to the factory defaults.  We didn't experience any kind of electrical outage: all the electrical clocks are still correct.

Is an ISP is able to send a signal that does a factory reset of the router-modem even when it is a third-party device? Or is the router manufacturer able to communicate with its routers and push an update and initiate a reset that would cause this sort of "hiccup"?

Remote management is [ ] unchecked for both HTTP and HTTPS.

C7000v2 Firmware: V1.03.08 (compatible with my ISP) per [Netgear](https://kb.netgear.com/000036375/What-is-the-latest-firmware-version-of-my-NETGEAR-cable-modem-or-modem-router).

This is what I found in the logs:

```
2024-1-27, 07:55:00 Critical (3)    Resetting the cable modem due to docsDevResetNow;
1970-1-1, 00:00:38  Critical (3)    SYNC Timing Synchronization failure - Failed to acquire QAM/QPSK symbol timing;
2024-1-27, 06:57:55 Critical (3)    No Ranging Response received - T3 time-out;
2024-1-27, 06:57:47 Critical (3)    SYNC Timing Synchronization failure - Failed to acquire QAM/QPSK symbol timing;
2024-1-27, 06:57:46 Critical (3)    No UCDs Received - Timeout;
2024-1-27, 06:57:27 Critical (3)    SYNC Timing Synchronization failure - Failed to acquire QAM/QPSK symbol timing;
2024-1-27, 06:57:26 Critical (3)    No UCDs Received - Timeout;
2024-1-27, 06:57:07 Critical (3)    SYNC Timing Synchronization failure - Failed to acquire QAM/QPSK symbol timing;
```

Comment: Is remote administration turned off in your router? Check also for firmware updates.

Comment: Finally found my way past a recursive "reset admin password" screen that kept taking me back to itself after I reset the password and chose two security questions. Will update question with what I found in the logs.

Comment: “Is an ISP is able to send a signal that does a factory reset of the router-modem even when it is a third-party device?” Could be that your third-party device is similar to the ISPs “first-party” device and they sent a command to update firmware, but in your case it just reset your router’s firmware. ISPs routinely update firmware on devices they own that are connected to their network.

Comment: I cannot find any setting that prohibits firmware updates. Would there be a log entry if the firmware had been updated?

Comment: 1) The term to search for is "docsDevResetNow". 2) You can usually backup the router's config to a PC, so for next time...

Comment: I found earlier references (from previous year) to the current firmware version so it was definitely initiated by the ISP and not a firmware update.

Comment: Could this odd occurrence be [related to this](https://arstechnica.com/security/2024/01/chinese-malware-removed-from-soho-routers-after-fbi-issues-covert-commands/)? Can’t find a list of affected devices, but this seems to be something worth mentioning. “[Chinese malware removed from SOHO routers after FBI issues covert commands](https://arstechnica.com/security/2024/01/chinese-malware-removed-from-soho-routers-after-fbi-issues-covert-commands/).”

Comment: @Giacomo1968 "The affidavit said elsewhere that the prevention measures would be neutralized if the routers were restarted. These devices would then be once again vulnerable to infection."   And the "docsDevResetNow" command can be sent over the wire and do just that, right?

Comment: @Tim I guess? Don’t know for sure. Worth thinking it’s a possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After several years of working 100% reliably,

That's a very normal kind of failure. Maybe not *expected,* but that's literally how things break.

**For example**, the flash memory that the router uses to store its configuration might slowly degrade due to some issue (whether physical or software-induced). There is almost always some kind of error correction in storage, which works up to a certain limit, e.g. it might recover from "up to X incorrect bits" which means bit errors could gradually rise and it'll *appear to* work 100% reliably without you knowing about that... until the amount exceeds X, at which point a sector or two will become completely unreadable and [the configuration can no longer be loaded] / [the firmware fails to start] / etc.

We've had a few Wi-Fi access points that had their flash memory fail; some would occasionally crash and reboot without anyone noticing – it still works and nobody is logging in to the settings page where the orange "Crash report" banner pops up – from the outside, though, it looked like it kept working reliably right until it rebooted one final time. (More than once, it had deteriorated to the point where you *couldn't* even log in to the settings page, because the firmware couldn't read "login.html" from flash anymore, but it still kept serving Wi-Fi for several months straight with what was still in RAM.)

> Is an ISP is able to send a signal that does a factory reset of the router-modem even when it is a third-party device

<del>No, usually not, but...</del> Many routers come with TR-069 capability (the CPE management protocol that many ISPs use), and *normally* it's supposed to be used with devices that the ISP has pre-provisioned with the server address *before* issuing them to customers, but I've actually heard somewhere™ that TR-069 *does* support a kind of auto-provisioning over DHCP where your TR-069-capable router automatically signs up to be managed by the ISP the first time it's connected, and *then* it can be reset by the ISP. (Maybe even by accident, if their system thinks it's configuring a completely different kind of device.)

**Edit:** Your edit says that it's specifically a DOCSIS cable modem. I'm completely unfamiliar with cable modems, but from what I understand, they *do* typically enroll with the ISP's remote management system (hence the whole page NETGEAR has about which ISPs support which firmware versions and so on), so this could certainly happen.

> Or is the router manufacturer able to communicate with its routers and push an update and initiate a reset that would cause this sort of "hiccup"?

Generally not<sup>1</sup>. But some router models will automatically *pull* software updates like your PC does (usually a better option than the many routers that get zero updates ever and then one day you find them running an uninvited Bitcoin miner or something). In theory, such an update should retain all configuration, but... even the update process isn't always programmed to be problem-free.

<sup>1</sup> Well, some equipment *does* have a "cloud management" option where it can be controlled by the manufacturer's server (mainly for central management of many devices), in which case the manufacturer could potentially reset your device, but I don't think I've heard that happen. Usually the manufacturer would show up on the news pretty fast if they got caught poking around like that.